How to find invisible characters in macOS Music app song tags?
I have discovered in my macOS Music app library that I have tracks/songs whose song titles include hidden special Unicode/ASCII characters. I can see this because they look like incorrect letter spacing in the list view, and when I copy their titles and paste them into a simple text editor, they appear. For example: <0x08> or <0x1d>
Is there a way to search for or create a smart playlist of all tracks containing non-alphanumeric letters, or some similar way to locate and delete them? If I attempt to search for or create a smart playlist with such a character pasted into place, no results are found.
